# Junit multiple expected exceptions of same type in one test case

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a junit test case to for a class that calculates area of a Rectangle. The method `calculateArea()` throws an `IllegalArugmentException` if the arguments passed to method are invalid.

Is it a bad practice to have multiple asserts that throw the same exception in a single test case? Do I need to have each Assert in a different test case?

Example:-

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestRectangle {

    @Test(expected = IllegalArugmentException.class)
    public void testCalculateAreaWithNegativeSides() {
        Rectangle.calculateArea(-10, 1);
        Rectangle.calculateArea(-10, -15);
        Rectangle.calculateArea(4, -5);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the first call already throws the exception... how can you be sure that the other two work as expected?

Comment: This is bad practice. Only test one assertion per test case, because when the first method call fails and throws an exception, the other two will not execute. The last two method calls are therefore effectively dead code.

I would suggest using something like JunitParams https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams to test multiple sets of parameters for the same test case.